# How do I add 3 products to my products list at time and show 3 more products at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've a listTree node variable which shows a tree view of nodes of different products in the following code :

```
var listTree = [{
        text: "الأثاث المنزلي",
        tags: [9,
            'أصناف',
            7,
            'موردين'
        ],

        products: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'ثلاجة نص أوتوماتيك',
                description: 'ثلاجة نص مش فل أوتوماتيك',
                supplier: 'شركة طلال للتجارة و التسويق',
                category: 'الأجهزة الكهربائية',
                accPrice: 120,
                outPrice: 160,
                discount: '25%',
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 2,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 160,
                outPrice: 200,
                discount: '20%',
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 4,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 500,
                outPrice: 600,
                discount: '17%',
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 3,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 400,
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 120,
                outPrice: 160,
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 120,
                outPrice: 160,
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: 'images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'ثلاجة نص أوتوماتيك',
                description: 'ثلاجة نص مش فل أوتوماتيك',
                supplier: 'شركة طلال للتجارة و التسويق',
                category: 'الأجهزة الكهربائية',
                accPrice: 120,
                outPrice: 160,
                discount: '25%',
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 2,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 160,
                outPrice: 200,
                discount: '20%',
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 4,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 500,
                outPrice: 600,
                discount: '17%',
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 3,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 400,
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 120,
                outPrice: 160,
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                name: 'منتج',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                supplier: 'مورد',
                category: 'تصنيف',
                accPrice: 120,
                outPrice: 160,
                images: [
                    './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                    './images/logo.jpg',
                ],
                img: 'images/mqdefault.jpg',
                rate: 1,
                quantity: 1,
            }
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: "أخرى",
                products: [{
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: 120,
                        outPrice: 160,
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 1,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: 120,
                        outPrice: 160,
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 2,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: 120,
                        outPrice: 160,
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 4,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: '$120',
                        outPrice: '$160',
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 4,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },

                ],
            },
            {
                text: "مظلة خارجية",
                tags: [2,
                    'أصناف',
                    3,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                products: [{
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: '$120',
                        outPrice: '$160',
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 1,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: '$120',
                        outPrice: '$160',
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 1,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        name: 'منتج',
                        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                        supplier: 'مورد',
                        category: 'تصنيف',
                        accPrice: '$120',
                        outPrice: '$160',
                        images: [
                            './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                            './images/logo.jpg',
                        ],
                        img: './images/mqdefault.jpg',
                        rate: 1,
                        quantity: 1,
                    }
                ],

            },
            {
                text: "ملحقات أثاث منزلي",
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "أثاث غرفة النوم",
                tags: [4,
                    'أصناف',
                    3,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 4'
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                text: "طاولات",
                tags: [6,
                    'أصناف',
                    2,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                    text: 'Child 1'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 2'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 3'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 4'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 5'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 6'
                }]
            },
            {
                text: "مجالس",
                tags: [4,
                    'أصناف',
                    2,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 4'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'مفروشات',
                tags: [4,
                    'أصناف',
                    4,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 4'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'إضاءات',
                tags: [2,
                    'أصناف',
                    0,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },

                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'خزانات',
                tags: [6,
                    'أصناف',
                    3,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                    text: 'Child 1'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 2'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 3'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 4'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 5'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 6'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "الأجهزة الكهربائية",
        tags: [6,
            'أصناف',
            2,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'أدوات المطبخ',
                tags: [11,
                    'أصناف',
                    2,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                    text: 'Child 1'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 2'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 3'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 4'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 5'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 6'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 7'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 8'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 9'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 10'
                }, {
                    text: 'Child 11'
                }],
            },
            { text: 'غرفة جلوس' },
            {
                text: 'مستلزمات منزل',
                tags: [3,
                    'أصناف',
                    7,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3'
                    }
                ]
            },
            { text: 'أدوات مطبخ' },
            {
                text: 'أجهزة العناية بالملابس',
                tags: [5,
                    'أصناف',
                    4,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'

                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 4'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 5'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'أجهزة الصحة و الجمال',
                tags: [3,
                    'أصناف',
                    7,
                    'موردين'
                ],
                nodes: [{
                        text: 'Child 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3'
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]

    },
    {
        text: "صالات الأفراح",
        tags: [1,
            'أصناف',
            7,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
            text: 'Child 1'
        }]

    },
    {
        text: "بدل الزفاف",
        tags: [9,
            'أصناف',
            7,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
            text: 'Child 1'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 2'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 3'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 4'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 5'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 6'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 7'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 8'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 9'
        }]
    },
    {
        text: "الكوافيرات",
        tags: [3,
            'أصناف',
            10,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "بطاقات الأفراح",
        tags: [2,
            'أصناف',
            6,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "تزيين الورود",
        tags: [4,
            'أصناف',
            7,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 3'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 4'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "تأجير الباصات",
        tags: [5,
            'أصناف',
            10,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 3'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 4'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 5'
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        text: "استوديوهات التصوير",
        tags: [3,
            'أصناف',
            11,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "المطابخ",
        tags: [3,
            'أصناف',
            3,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "الفنادق",
        tags: [1,
            'أصناف',
            1,
            'موردين'
        ],
        nodes: [{
            text: 'Child 1'
        }]
    },
    {
        text: "تأجير السيارات",
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "فنون إستعراضية",
        nodes: [{
                text: 'Child 1'
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "المسارح",
        nodes: [{
            text: 'Child 1'
        }]
    },
    {
        text: "شركات التنظيف",
        nodes: [{
            text: 'Child 1'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 2'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 3'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 4'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 5'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 6'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 7'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 8'
        }]
    },
    {
        text: "بدل رجالي",
        nodes: [{
            text: 'Child 1'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 2'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 3'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 4'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 5'
        }, {
            text: 'Child 6'
        }]
    }
];
```

and on the click of a node, the products object in the node displays the products in node selected  as I've done in the following :

```
$('#tree').treeview({
    data: listTree,
    collapseIcon: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    expandIcon: 'fas fa-chevron-down',
    uncheckedIcon: 'far fa-square',
    checkedIcon: 'fas fa-check-square',
    showCheckbox: 'true',
    showTags: 'true',
    onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
        $productsList.html('');
        for (let i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
            $productsList.append(addProducts(data.products[i]));
        }


        $productsList.show();

        if (data.tags) {
            $productsQuantity.html(data.tags[0]);
            $suppliersQuantity.html(data.tags[2]);
            $productsQuantity.show();
            $suppliersQuantity.show();
        }
    },
    onNodeUnselected: function(event, data) {
        $productsList.hide();
    }
});
```

The products are added through the addProduct(product) function which is just template for how the products are added in the row of #productsList.

```
function addProducts(product) {
    let body = '';
    body += "<div class='col-sm-4' data-action='addToCart' data-product='" + JSON.stringify(product) + "' product>";
    body += "<div class='card' style='cursor:pointer';>";
    body += "<img class='card-img-top' style='width:100%;height:25%;'" + " src=" + product.img + " alt='card image'>";
    body += "<div class='card-body'>";
    body += "<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>";
    body += "<h6 class='card-title' style='margin:auto 0;'> " + product.name + "</h6>";
    body += "<p style='margin:auto 0;'>" + product.id + "</p>";
    body += "</div>";
    body += "<div class='d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center mb-1' id='category-supplier'>";
    body += "<p>" + product.category + "</p>";
    body += "<p>" + product.supplier + "</p>";
    body += "</div>";
    if (product.discount) {
        body += "<div class='bg-light text-dark d-flex justify-content-around' style='padding:0.2rem 0.2rem;font-size:0.6rem;margin:0 0.2rem;'>";
        body += "<p class='d-flex m-1'>" + "<span style='margin:0 0.3rem;'>" + product.discount + "</span>" + "<del>" + product.outPrice + "</del><i class='fas fa-shekel-sign' style='margin-right:0.2rem;'></i>" + "</p>";
        body += "<p class='d-flex m-1'>" + product.accPrice + "<i class='fas fa-shekel-sign' style='margin-right:0.2rem;'></i>" + "</p>";
        body += "</div>";
    } else {
        body += "<div class='bg-light text-dark d-flex justify-content-around' style='padding:0.2rem 0.2rem;font-size:0.6rem;margin:0 0.2rem;'>";
        body += "<p class='d-flex m-1'>" + product.accPrice + "<i class='fas fa-shekel-sign' style='margin-right:0.2rem;'></i>" + "</p>";
        body += "</div>";
    }

    body += "<div class='m-1'><small class='text-muted'>" + product.description + "</small></div>";
    body += "<div class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary showMore' data-action='showMore' style='width:100%;padding:0.3rem 0.3rem' data-toggle='modal'>" + "معرفة المزيد" + "</button></div>";
    body += "</div>";

    body += "</div>";
    body += "</div>";
    body += "</div>";
    return body;
}
```

How can I add 3 products at a time and on the click of a 'show more' button I get to add 3 more items ?
I've tried making a numberOfProducts variable which starts at 3 and adds 3 items at a item. The tree traverses the length of the numberOfProducts variable and displays the products, but they are only displayed on the check of the node through the onNodeChecked object.

```
var numberOfProducts = 3;

$('.btn-showMore .btn-info').click(function() {
    numberOfProduct += 3;
});

$('#tree').treeview({
    data: listTree,
    collapseIcon: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    expandIcon: 'fas fa-chevron-down',
    uncheckedIcon: 'far fa-square',
    checkedIcon: 'fas fa-check-square',
    showCheckbox: 'true',
    showTags: 'true',
    onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
        $productsList.html('');
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfProducts; i++) {
            $productsList.append(addProducts(data.products[i]));
        }


        $productsList.show();

        if (data.tags) {
            $productsQuantity.html(data.tags[0]);
            $suppliersQuantity.html(data.tags[2]);
            $productsQuantity.show();
            $suppliersQuantity.show();
        }
    },
    onNodeUnselected: function(event, data) {
        $productsList.hide();
    }
});
```